# How to copy iPhone Notes to Pages

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, pages, notes.app

How can I copy all of my IPhone Notes that are in ICloud into a Pages doc. I have been googling this for a couple of days but haven't found any answer. I don't want to use iTunes & a computer. There should be a simple way to move all my notes into one Pages doc.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get notes out from the device itself using a idevice explorer such as iTools or iFunbox, but with some research the tutorials and questions for "where's the notes stored on my idevice" is outdated and doesn't work with iOS 8 ~~~

So, doing it manually, I recommend hooking up your iCloud to the notes, (which you've already done) and load it up on your mac using the Notes app. Open Pages alongside, and copy and paste the good old fashioned way. Command+c and command+v

> I don't want to use iTunes & a computer. There should be a simple way to move all my notes into one Pages doc.

You could do this on your iPhone/iPad too

Answer (score 0):

I love attaching a Bluetooth keyboard to my iPhone for tasks like this. You can even use the USB camera adapter to connect many USB wired keyboards which lets you use the key commands to select all text, copy the text, command tab to switch to the other app and then paste the text and app switch back to the first app.

With a keyboard any iOS device you have all the affordances of a computer with none of the size restrictions.